# openssl returning "Verify return code: 0 (ok)" for expired certficiate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using `openssl` to look at a certificate which appears to be expired:

```sh
# Write the certificate chain to a file
</dev/null openssl s_client -showcerts -connect testauth.assurity.com:443 > cert-chain.pem
# Separate chain into individual certificate files
csplit -z -f chain-link- cert-chain.pem '/--BEGIN CERT/' '{*}'
# Output the hash and dates for each certificate
for f in chain-link-01 chain-link-02 chain-link-03; do
  openssl x509 -noout -enddate -hash -subject -in $f
done
```

The openssl output for chain-link-03 includes the line `notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT`; it's an expired certificate. Yet I get two different outcomes when I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect testauth.assurity.com:443` from two different machines:

1. From my workstation, openssl outputs `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`
2. From my server, openssl outputs `Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)`

What's going on here? Running the script above on both my workstation and server outputs a hash and subject for each certificate, revealing that the two machines are receiving the *same certificates* from `testauth.assurity.com:443`. *I wonder why only one of the two machines returns a non-zero and whether I need to contact Assurity to have them update their cert.*

**Bottom line**: I'm running a ruby-on-rails app which makes successful requests to `testauth.assurity.com` from my workstation but not from my server. On the server, the ruby-on-rails app refuses to issue a request, stating:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR: it's probably an alternate path**

Most publicly issued certs today use one intermediate CA, so 01 would be your leaf cert, 02 the intermediate CA, and 03 could be either a root cert (which is superfluous) *or* a 'bridge' aka 'cross' cert for that root from a *different* root. This is usually done when a new CA is created and initially not in the truststores of existing systems, platforms, and libraries; it is 'cross-signed' by a different, existing and already-trusted CA. However, even when the new CA subsequently does have its (own) root cert trusted, servers often continue serving the (obsolete) bridge cert because it ain't broke.

For a convenient example, this has happened *twice* with Google. Google used to obtain certs for its sites under GeoTrust, which was bridged under Equifax back in the early years of this century; see for example
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93081/gmail-x-509-certificate-chain
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171983/server-certificate-terminates-in-removed-ca-certificate-still-works
https://serverfault.com/questions/841036/openssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-for-accounts-google-com
After GeoTrust was tainted in the Symantec misissuance issue (tongue-twister!), Google switched to be under GlobalSign but *also* started getting its own root in trust programs, and today https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.google.com&s=216.58.195.68&hideResults=on&ignoreMismatch=on shows two leaf certs being used (one RSA, one EC) both under `GTS CA 1C3` which in turn can be verified by the bridge to `GlobalSign Root CA` but also directly by `GTS Root R1` (which SSLLabs shows, confusingly, *both* as 'in trust store' *and* 'extra download'!) "GTS" means Google Trust Services, i.e. their CA.

A similar case could occur if 02 is a bridge to an older root 03, and a newer root for the same CA as 02 (same Subject and SKI if present) is available, but that would mean the leaf cert is issued directly by a root, which violates CABforum rules; that could be an inhouse or private CA that doesn't follow public rules, but then I would expect it to be manually maintained in *all* the systems you use and not vary.

Thus I retro-dict that your workstation has in its truststore a (probably newer) direct root for the same CA as in your 03 cert, but your server does not and thus continues to use the expired-and-invalid bridge. It is also conceivable that the server has the root but uses an old (pre-1.0.2) version of OpenSSL that doesn't implement the alternate chain logic, but in 2021 that's not very likely.

I can't verify myself, because neither my system nor SSLLabs can connect to `testauth.assurity.com` (resolved to 216.229.15.88).